# Срабатывает только первый клик

Tags: jquery

Нужно что бы при клике по картинке внутри блока .ad_b срабатывала функция. Блоков с этим классом и картинкой внутри может быть несколько. Делаю так, но работает только на первой картинке, на остальных не хочет.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.ad_b img').click(function(){
alert('ok');
});
});
```

Comment: вынеси за  $(document).ready

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan вроде помогло, а в чём собственно трабла?

Comment: По моему DOM еще не подгружен,вот и не находит .

Comment: Если помогло поставь пожалуйста галочку чтобы закрыть тему.Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

во первых убедись что они есть в DOM дереве

```
console.log($('.ad_b img'))
```

вынеси за  `$(document).ready`.

если не сработает то может быть они добавляются после загрузки `DOM`.
Тогда так:

```
$(document).find('.ad_b img').on('click',function(){alert('ok');});
```

если опять не сработает то проблема не в коdе .

Comment: Да верно ,если узел добавляется в дерево после его отрисовки с помощью append или аналогичным способом,то прочесть его можно через $(document).find('selector')